# Nodejs-Get multiple data at once

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I have an `accordion` and in each `panel` I have different `forms` but with multiple `inputs` and `checkboxes`. 
I would like to submit once for getting all data and store them (in json format for exemple) for using the one that I need when I want to do smthg else with. 
My question is, when I get data from my html page, is there a way to get all the data in once without using `req.body.name_of_input` or `req.body.name_checkboxes` as many times as I have inputs and checkboxes?

Comment: How about just storing `req.body`? It's a little bit unclear what you are actually trying to do - save the data you got by the form at once inside a Database or something?

Comment: Yeah I know it could be a bit unclear! Sorry English is not my native language! The thing is I need to use them as input for the nodejs nools I developed! I knew about req.body but then how can I access a specific data?

Comment: Just as you could send everything as an object, you can also retrieve them as an object using the `req.body` .